# Cannot find type System.Windows.Media.AudioSink in module System.Windows.dll for windows 8

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

In my Windows Store Application, I am getting the error:

`Cannot find type System.Windows.Media.AudioSink in module System.Windows.dll`

I tried to add a reference to it, but I can't find an assembly list in my project's references.

My system:

- OS - Windows 8.1
- IDE - Visual studio 2013

Answer (score 0):

The .NET Core for Windows Store Applications does not include all of .NET 4.5 (nor 4.5.1). It is a subset of it, meaning that not all classes are included. It also has some classes specific to it.

If you want to do audio, you should look into the [Getting Started with Audio and Video](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465160.aspx) tutorial that Microsoft created for this very purpose.

Also, in the future you should probably include what language you are using. There are multiple languages that Windows Store Apps can be created in (C#,C++/XAML, Javascript/HTML), and it helps to know that.